# How can I pass text from <a> to textarea on another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, product

What I want is pretty much the most basic `Add product to enquiries` you can get.

On my product page there will be a button `add to enquiries`.

Now how can I pass just that product name when clicking on the `add to enquries` button to the enquiries page. That name must then be entered into a textarea field.

I would prefer to do this using Javascript or JQuery if I can.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Retro8901 
Please go through the SO guidelines regarding asking a "good" question. This question right now is very open ended and there are many possible solutions - though the commonly used practice is using Cookies. You can google how to store and read cookies - and ask a question if you get stuck somewhere. 

And before asking a question, (1) Google, (2) Search stackoverflow for potential solutions, (3) Ask a concrete question.

All the best.

Comment: You could extract the text using and save it either on local storage or as a parameter to your link. Then on the new page you can get that data back from the local storage,  or from the parameters of your link.

Comment: The question is way too broad, as there are multiple solutions to this. One would be to parse whatever you want as get variables directly into the link in question, another would be to make an AJAX function handle it through that, etc. You should take note of past comments as to how one should use Stackoverflow.

Comment: @ConstantinChirila Thank you for your assistance. Could you perhaps give me an example of doing this by adding parameters to my links and getting that data into the textarea from the link?

Comment: @everyone sorry everyone, I'm brand new to Stackoverflow. Taking note of all your suggestions.

Comment: @Retr8901 I've added it as an answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: @ConstantinChirila Thanks for your help and advice. I'll have a look at local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this. For example, in the product page, when the button is clicked, you can store it in localstorage as:

```
function addToEnquiries(){
let productName= document.getElementById("productName").value;
localStorage.setItem("product",productName);
}
```

Then on page load of the Enquiries page, you can retrieve it as:

```
function onPageLoad(){
console.log("Product name is ",localStorage.getItem("product"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Author request here's one way of using parameters in urls.

Solution from [here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html).

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

Assuming the url is `http://dummy.com/?textareaContent=loremispum` you can get the parameters like this.

```
var tech = getUrlParameter('textareaContent');
```

But be careful, if you are adding text to the link it needs to be encoded and then decoded. Here is some documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

I still suggest using local storage is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just for adding multiple products just modify little bit of codingsplash's answer

```
function addToEnquiries(){
    var productName = document.getElementById("productName").value;
    var product = localStorage.getItem('product');
    if(!product)
    {
        product = new Array();
    }
        product.push(productName);
        localStorage.setItem("product",product);
    }
}
```